# Python list at module level

Tags: python

I broke down my problem to the following example program

```
xy8_block = [
    {'pulse': {}},
]

class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, block=list(xy8_block)):
        self._block = block


dumdum = Dummy()
dumdum._block[0]['pulse']['test'] = 0
print(xy8_block)
```

If I run the program, the variable `xy8_block` 
is changed, although both variables `dumdum._block` and
`xy8_block` have both a different memory address.

How can I avoid this problem without directly initialising
the class with the value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti is correct, you can prove this by looking at the ids of the dictionary : ``print id(xy8_block[0]) `` and ``print id(dumdum._block[0])``

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
def __init__(self, block=list(xy8_block)):
```

Do:

```
from copy import deepcopy
def __init__(self, block=deepcopy(xy8_block)):
```

When you do `list(my_list)`, you do a **shallow** copy of your list, which means its elements are still copied by reference.

In other words, as you correctly mentioned, `xy8_block` and `dumdum._block` do have different memory addresses. However, if you check memory addresses for `xy8_block[0]` and `dumdum._block[0]`, you will see that they are the same.

By using `deepcopy`, you copy the list **and** its elements' values, not their references.

**EDIT**

As wisely noted by @FMc, this will still make all instances' `_block` attributes to point to the same object, since the list that results from `deepcopy` is created in the method's definition, not in its execution. So here's my suggestion:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, block=None):
        self._block = block or deepcopy(xy8_block)
```

Comment: This won't work as intended. Every instance of `Dummy` will hold a reference to the same deep copy. Default arg values are defined once, at class definition time. That's one reason why you typically want to avoid mutable values as default values.

Comment: Although it does work for the specific given example, you're right about that. I will elaborate, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Get a fresh block each time:

```
def new_xy8_block():
    return [{'pulse': {}}]

class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, block=None):
        self._block = block or new_xy8_block()

ds = [Dummy() for _ in range(5)]
ds[0]._block[0]['pulse']['test'] = 0

for d in ds:
    print d._block
```